# How to change date format in jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Is there any possible to change date format in `jdbcTemplate`. For example i have this code:

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> items = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql)
```

and it reurn result something like this:

```
ChangedOn -> {LocalDateTime@13522} "2022-04-21T13:37:52"
CreatedOn -> {LocalDateTime@13524} "2022-04-19T12:24:26
```

Is there any possible to format to this LocalDateTime:

```
 public static final String DATETIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed by myself, need just override one method in class `ColumnMapRowMapper`:

```
public class MyColumnMapRowMapper extends ColumnMapRowMapper {

    public static final String DATETIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        Map<String, Object> mapOfColumnValues = createColumnMap(columnCount);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String column = JdbcUtils.lookupColumnName(rsmd, i);
            Object columnValue = convertDate(getColumnValue(rs, i));

            mapOfColumnValues.putIfAbsent(getColumnKey(column), columnValue);
        }
        return mapOfColumnValues;
    }

    private Object convertDate(final Object columnValue) {
        if (columnValue != null && columnValue
            .getClass()
            .equals(LocalDateTime.class)) {
            return ((LocalDateTime) columnValue).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATETIME_FORMAT));
        } else {
            return columnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And then override one more method in the class `JdbcTemplate`:

```
  jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource) {
            @Override
            protected RowMapper<Map<String, Object>> getColumnMapRowMapper() {
                return new MyColumnMapRowMapper();
            }
        };
```